# C Programming: Linked Lists

Tags: linked-list, nested-lists

I'm writing a program using linked list (such a nightmare).

Anyway, the purpose of the program is to enter 8 characters and have the program print the characters back out to you and also print the characters back out in reverse order, using linked lists of course.

I got this so far. There's a lot wrong with it (i think).

Problems are

- When asking for characters from the user it should read in the amount of characters automatically without having to ask for how many characters
- Also, when it it compiles it prints gibberish to the screen, for example I just ran it and it printed

  ```
  ¿r
    (àõ($ê¿¿  
  a¿r
  (àõ($ê¿¿  

  ¿r
    (àõ($ê¿¿  
  b¿r
     (àõ($ê¿¿
  ```

Lots of help needed here. It would be so much appreciated!

Code of course

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define strsize 30

typedef struct member
{
    int number;
    char fname[strsize];
    struct member *next;
}
RECORD;

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it);
RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j);

int main (void)
{
    int i, result;
    RECORD *head, *p;
    head=NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of characters: ");
    scanf("%d", &result);

    for (i=1; i<=result; i++)
        head=insert (head);
    print (head, result);

    return 0;
}

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it)
{
    RECORD *cur, *q;
    int num;
    char junk;
    char first[strsize];
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf("%c", &first);

    cur=(RECORD *) malloc(sizeof(RECORD));

    strcpy(cur->fname, first);
    cur->next=NULL;

    if (it==NULL)
        it=cur;
    else
    {
        q=it;
        while (q->next!=NULL)
            q=q->next;
        q->next=cur;
    }
    return (it);
}

RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j)
{
    RECORD *cur;
    cur=it;
    int i;  
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
        printf("%s  \n", cur->fname);
        cur=cur->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please use the code button ({}) to make your source code readable please. and obviously there are some stuff missing after include.

Comment: it is homework! I'm just looking for some help

Comment: That's the thing I did as much as I could I just don't know where to go from here. I'm not looking for code just for what's wrong and where to fix

Comment: An important trick to learn early on is to write a small bit of code, test it so you know it works, and then build on it.  It is much easier to find and correct problems this way than testing it all at once.

Comment: I wish there was stackoverflow around when I had to do my homework. :) Once you have your input running, using phoxis suggestions, you will also find out (probably) that you are not printing things out in the right (reverse) order. You will need a doubly-linked list to traverse it reversed, or.. you could also use some clever recursion to have the recursed function first go down a level before outputting its own (character) value when going through the list. Mind you, there should be about 100 articles and ready solutions on this out there for someone taking the time to search. :)

Comment: do you have to do the reverse thing with a linked list ?

Answer (score 3):

You have:

in insert:

```
char first[strsize];

scanf("%c", &first);  /* note the %c */

strcpy(cur->fname, first);
```

in print

```
printf("%s  \n", cur->fname);
```

You should have `%s` instead of `%c` and therefore change `&format` to `format` in the argument list, as `format` itself represents the address of the location the string is to be stored.

So the `scanf` call should be like below

```
scanf("%s", first);
```

Another thing. If you have specified a return type in the `print` function then you should return something, or make it return nothing (declare return type as `void`). This will not pose any problem in this case although.

Read the warning messages which the compiler throws to you and you would see the compiler actually had answered your questions.

You need to do some redesigns i think. For example to traverse the linked list you do not need to counter 'j'. you can detect the list termination by inspecting if the `next` link is NULL or not.

Your question was to print the characters or strings in reverse, so you need to write some other print function than what you have wrote.

Comment: Correct! Also it's not printing the characters in reverse order at all. Doesn't even look like Jennifer took a stab at that part.